# Python Opencv: how to calculate the number of pixels that belong to the sky in a picture over total

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am currently learning opencv to process images in Python.
I have some pictures and I should detect which part of the picture represents the sky: then, I should calculate the number of pixels that belong to the sky over the total.
In your opinion, is there a way to do this with opencv or should I train a neural network to recognize the sky in a series of pictures?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I tried thresholding, countouring, background subtraction in opencv

Comment: Show us your picture and your advancement first,
Using a neural network for this would be brutal. How would you even train it first ?
This can be done quickly via opencv or numpy or PIL ...

Comment: Night sky or day sky?

Comment: day sky would sufficient

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

imho, a CNN for that is a bit overpowered. Personally, I would try to select all the correlated pixel, starting from a targeted one that surely represent the sky. (something like the luminance/color picker implemented in adobe camera raw)

Comment: In case of a day sky, plotting the histogram of the blue channel for the whole image, should give you an idea on the 'luminosity' range to keep in mind!

Comment: all of that is relative to whatever exposure settings the camera decides to set itself to... so, no, specific luminance thresholds will make no sense.